# Archive file can't find the identifier name

Tags: iphone, ios, ipa

I can't build the .ipa file from my application. It's successfully run in the simulator and in my real device. Now when i press 'Product->archive' to build the archive, it's successfully archive the project but it losses the identifier name and version is 'Unspecified'. When i press the share button it's didn't find the provisioning profile and can't build the ipa file…

How can i solve this problem. ?
How can i get this ipa build file ?